# Why is 'reset' event not triggered on Collection.fetch() in Backbone 1.0.0

Tags: backbone.js

I have a collection view with the followig code:

```
class FoosCollectionView extends Backbone.View
  el: '#foos'

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new FoosCollection [],
      barId: @options.barId
      foozId: @options.foozId

    @listenTo @collection, 'sync', @render
    @collection.fetch()

  template: MyApp.Templates.foos

  render: (event)->
    $(@el).html @template @collection
    @

FoosCollectionView
```

Before Backbone 1.0.0 a `reset` event was triggered when `fetch` on a collection completed. Now the `sync` event is triggered, but I dont know if this is due to a bug or if it is new standard behaviour.

Can anyone tell me, why `reset` is not triggered anymore?

Regards
Felix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the 1.0.0 changelog, I see:

> Renamed Collection's "update" to set, for parallelism with the similar
>   model.set(), and contrast with reset. **It's now the default updating
>   mechanism after a fetch.** If you'd like to continue using "reset", pass
>   {reset: true}.